# foreground iphone app causing my background app to crash

Tags: iphone, ios, crash, background-process

I have a map based and location based app which I put into the background. I then start a a game app (agent dash) after the game app has finished initializing I noticed that my app has been killed: 9 in the device log. Sometimes I get a memory warning message, sometimes not. But is it possible for one app to cause another to be terminated. If I run the my app on its own there is no problem. I run other apps in the foreground and no problem. Also if an app can cause mine to be terminated can I generate a restart? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Agent dash must be an memory intensive app, so when the iOS feels its running out of memory it generates memory warnings which each app needs to handle. It can even kill your app if it needs more memory. The primary thing iOS takes into consideration is that it wants to keep the app which the user is using alive. And no you can't restart your app pro grammatically the user will have to do it if he wants to.

Comment: Thanks for the info, that is disappointing, as I was looking to do some daily location analytics hence I needed the app to sit in the background and capture locations.  At least it means I won't send myself insane trying to find out why :-).  Is there any way i can post a notifcation if I get a memory warning in the background, at least the user will know the app is about to be nuked?

Comment: ios may kill you even without warning. I dont think you're notifications would be delivered -- dont know that for sure though ^^ -- in general you can post UILocalNotifications :D